# How to write expiry date issue in if condition

Tags: c#, sql-server

This code changes the row color when quantity decrease but now I need that to solve expiry problem like this

```
private void DgvStock_CellFormatting_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DgvStock.Rows)
    {
        int Qty = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].Value);
        if (Qty <= 10)
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking

Comment: When [your question is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53214091/) you should [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53216296/edit) to address the problems people pointed out. What you should not do is ask the same question again and ignore everything people commented.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, But as I have understood, Please check below code if it may helpful for you.

```
private void DgvStock_CellFormatting_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DgvStock.Rows)
    {
        int Qty = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].Value);
        if (Qty <= 10)
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }

DateTime exp = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["yourExpiryDateColumn"].Value);
        if (exp <= System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90))//Updated -90 days
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank You bro! it works, now just add 90 days with expiry date or  subtract 90 days from system date. it will solve my problem! i want that the row color is red when 90 days left to item expiry date thank u

Comment: In C#, You can modify dateTime by AddDays method. Please use this code. if (exp <= System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90)) // Here you are adding -90days that will subtract 90 days, if you give 90 means it will add same.
        {//Your code here }